# How to write a text in Terminal using AppleScript?

Tags: terminal, applescript

How can I insert a text into Terminal.app using AppleScript?
I don't mean to execute it (press Enter). Only to insert it.
My current script almost works:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "TextToInsert" using {}
end tell
```

The trouble is when this is executed by a hot key, e.g. CMD-T, and then the pressed CMD interferes with the keystrokes and changes the desired behavior.

I need either to tell the `keystroke` command to ignore any modifier keys or to use other command to write the text there. I think `write` should do it but have no idea how.

Comment: Using `using {}` does absolutely noting and if you're not using a modifier, it's not necessary. Also, Terminal's **AppleScript** Dictionary does not have or understand the `write` _command_; however, **iTerm2** does: **write** _v_ : Send text as though it was typed. BTW If Terminal is already running without a window or with a window minimized, `activate` will not cause a window to be created or unminimized a minimized window and the rest of you _code_ will fail, so you need to _code_ for these possibilities. Also, **⌘T** is already a default shortcut in Terminal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like, first copying the text to your clipboard, that you want inserted into Terminal, then have the AppleScript code paste the clipboard into Terminal.

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    tell application "System Events"
        tell application process "Terminal"
            set frontmost to true
            repeat while not frontmost
                delay 0.1
            end repeat
        end tell
        keystroke "v" using {command down}
    end tell
end tell
```

---

If you have all of your Terminal windows set to open in tabs rather than separate windows, this following AppleScript code should account for any of the situations as mentioned by @user3439894 in his comment to your post.

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    repeat until frontmost
        delay 0.5
    end repeat
    set windowCount to count of window
    if windowCount is not 0 then
        tell its front window
            set isMinimized to miniaturized
        end tell
    end if

    if windowCount is 0 then
        tell application "System Events" to tell application process "Terminal"
            set frontmost to true
            repeat while not frontmost
                delay 0.1
            end repeat
            keystroke "n" using {command down}
            delay 1
            keystroke "v" using {command down}
        end tell
    else
        activate
        repeat until frontmost
            delay 0.5
        end repeat
        delay 0.1
        if ((processes of selected tab of front window) is {} or isMinimized) then
            tell application "System Events" to tell application process "Terminal"
                set frontmost to true
                repeat while not frontmost
                    delay 0.1
                end repeat
                keystroke "n" using {command down}
                delay 1
                keystroke "v" using {command down}
            end tell
        else
            tell application "System Events" to tell application process "Terminal"
                set frontmost to true
                repeat while not frontmost
                    delay 0.1
                end repeat
                delay 0.5
                keystroke "v" using {command down}
            end tell
        end if
    end if
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

I've marked the above answer as correct even though it did not solve my problem because there is a lot of other useful code.

My unsolved issues:
1. modifier keys are still interfering even with CMD-c trick
2. Clipboard trick alters the clipboard. I could set it back to original value but that changes the history.

My solution:
Don't run the script till any modifier keys are pressed. It's also kind of a trick but it solves the root-cause.

Here is my code:

```
- (void) cmd_panel_curItem_sendPathToTerminal;
{
    if (self.noKeyModifiersTimer != nil) {
        return;
    }
    self.noKeyModifiersTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(_cmd_panel_curItem_sendPathToTerminal) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void) _cmd_panel_curItem_sendPathToTerminal;
{
    NSUInteger modifiers = ([NSEvent modifierFlags] & NSEventModifierFlagDeviceIndependentFlagsMask);

    if ((modifiers & NSEventModifierFlagOption) == 0 && (modifiers & NSEventModifierFlagShift) == 0 && (modifiers & NSEventModifierFlagCommand) == 0 && (modifiers & NSEventModifierFlagControl) == 0) {
        [self.noKeyModifiersTimer invalidate];
        self.noKeyModifiersTimer = nil;
        [self impl_panel_curItem_sendPathToTerminal];
    }
}

- (void) impl_panel_curItem_sendPathToTerminal;
{
    // orig code
}
```